# Recursion on subarrays with "child" key

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, tree

I have array of arrays - tree structure of main menu.
I try to find in this tree one node with needed `slug` and return this node with all it's childs.
I write little recurcive function

```
<?php
$tree = '[{"id":1,"structure":1,"parent":0,"slug":"medicinskaya-ge","child":{"2":{"id":2,"structure":1.1,"parent":1,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika","child":{"3":{"id":3,"structure":"1.1.1","parent":2,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika","datafile":"ssz","template":"ssz"},"4":{"id":4,"structure":"1.1.2","parent":2,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika","child":{"5":{"id":5,"structure":"1.1.2.1","parent":4,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika"},"6":{"id":6,"structure":"1.1.2.2","parent":4,"slug":"testirovanie-ge"},"7":{"id":7,"structure":"1.1.2.3","parent":4,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika"}}},"8":{"id":8,"structure":"1.1.3","parent":2,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika"},"9":{"id":9,"structure":"1.1.4","parent":2,"slug":"texnologiya-kol"}}}}}]';
$tree = json_decode($tree, true);


function getSlugData(string $slug, array $data)
{
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if ($row['slug'] == $slug) {
            return $row;
        }
        if (isset($row['child'])) {
            //return $this->getSlugData($slug, $row['child']);
        }
    }

    return [];
}


$result = getSlugData('testirovanie-ge', $tree);
print_r($result);
```

But as a result I have an empty array. If I `print_r($row)` when `$row['slug'] == $slug` - It appears on screen.

```
if ($row['slug'] == $slug) {
    exit(print_r($row));
    return $row;
}
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: Honestly, that's a single line of JSON with > 200 chars and a bunch of nested structs. Reduce that! Also, you can put the result of decoding it into the code, i.e. define an array, which you can format in a readable manner. Especially, when there is something in "child" but the code doesn't evaluate that anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In programming, recursion is a useful and powerful mechanism that allows a function to call itself directly or indirectly, that is, a function is said to be recursive if it contains at least one explicit or implicit call to itself.

I modified your code a bit and got the solution below.

```
$tree = '[{"id":1,"structure":1,"parent":0,"slug":"medicinskaya-ge","child":{"2":{"id":2,"structure":1.1,"parent":1,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika","child":{"3":{"id":3,"structure":"1.1.1","parent":2,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika","datafile":"ssz","template":"ssz"},"4":{"id":4,"structure":"1.1.2","parent":2,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika","child":{"5":{"id":5,"structure":"1.1.2.1","parent":4,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika"},"6":{"id":6,"structure":"1.1.2.2","parent":4,"slug":"testirovanie-ge"},"7":{"id":7,"structure":"1.1.2.3","parent":4,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika"}}},"8":{"id":8,"structure":"1.1.3","parent":2,"slug":"dnk-diagnostika"},"9":{"id":9,"structure":"1.1.4","parent":2,"slug":"texnologiya-kol"}}}}}]';
$tree = json_decode($tree, true);

//print_r($tree);
//die();

function getSlugData(string $slug, array $data, string $key = 'slug')
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        // Checks if the key exists and is the desired value for that key in the array
        if (isset($row[$key]) && $row[$key] === $slug) {
            return $row;
        }

        // If it is an array, apply recursion by calling getSlugData again
        if (is_array($row)) {
            $result = getSlugData($slug, $row, $key);
            if ($result !== []) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(getSlugData('testirovanie-ge', $tree));
print_r(getSlugData('texnologiya-kol', $tree));
print_r(getSlugData('nothing-here', $tree));
die();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the recursive function, you must not break the loop early unless you find your slug match.  If a non-slug-match has a child element, you must iterate it and potentially pass up a match in subsequent recursive calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7hgrP))

```
function getSlugData(string $slug, array $data): array
{
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if ($row['slug'] === $slug) {
            return $row;
        }
        if (isset($row['child'])) {
            $deeper = getSlugData($slug, $row['child']);
            if ($deeper) {
                return $deeper;
            }
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

P.s. you aren't calling a class method, so `$this->` is inappropriate.

Comment: @Tereto I want to bring to your attention that Benilson's answer is working harder than it needs to.  https://3v4l.org/ZfSXQ  For each element of each `$row`, his script is checking if `$row` is an array (yes, `$row` is ALWAYS an associative array).  This may be okay in a general-use function, it is doing wasteful checks on your data tree.  My script iterates each indexed row of each level, then specifically checks the `slug` or `child` keys and never anything more.  This means that my snippet is better tuned to your data. I hope I have clearly explained the advantage of my answer.